# How to access coefficient from VGAM package (generalized Poisson regression)

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, poisson-regression

I am interested to know, how to get the coefficient from VGAM package (generalized Poisson regression), because, when I want to get the coefficient, is just can to get the estimate with @ to get the estimate. An other coefficient can to get all of the part from coefficient with "$"...

My program like this:

```
library("VGAM")  
fit <- vglm(y ~ x1, genpoisson,trace = TRUE)  
summary(fit)  
hasilgp <- summary(fit)  
koefgp <- hasilgp@coefficients
```

And only the estimate can to attach...
Any one help me...

Comment: There are so many errors in the English that it is difficult to determine what the question is.  Any chance you can fix the grammatical mistakes?

Comment: I suspect this is actually an R question about the difference between working with `S3` classes (that are accessed via `$`) & `S4` classes (that are accessed via `@`). If you can improve the English, we can migrate this question to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) for you.

Comment: @gung is more than likely spot on, but the solution is probably **not** to delve into objects and rip out whatever you feel but to learn to use *extractor* functions, in this case `coefficients()` or its shorter alias `coef()`, as in `coef(fit)`

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore the differences if you use *extractor* functions rather than delve into model objects and take what you want. In this case, the correct extractor functions is `coefficients()` or its shorter alias `coef()`. This function has methods for a great number of model objects in R, written by the respective package authors so you *don't* have to wonder how to access aspects of the fit.

In this case try

```
coef(fit)
```

The distinction between accessing via `@` and `$` is, as @gung mentions, due to the use of S4 class objects in the **VGAM** package. Those objects have *slots* and the accessor function is `@`. `$` is used to access the components/elements of a list or data frame. S3 methods tend to return list objects describing the fit and hence you'll see people accessing those components with `$`.

In general, however, it is best to use extractor functions where available, e.g. `coef()`, `fitted()`, `predict()`, ....